# variable coefficient gurobi python

Tags: python, variables, gurobi, coefficients

I am using Gurobi and Python and I need to get the coefficient of a specific variable in all constraints in my MILP model. I know that there are some functions like `m.gtCol` or `m.getCoeff` to get the desired output. However, I could not use them in a proper way to return the coefficients. I defined my variable in this way:

```py
w = {}
for i in I:
    for n in N:
        for j in J:
            w[i,n,j] = m.addVar(vtype=GRB.BINARY, name='w_%d_%d_%d' % (i,n,j))
```

Anybody can help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gurobi/pQXRd37BQL8

```
[x for x in model.getVars() if x.VarName.find('w_1_1_1') != -1]
```

should give the list of variables that contain the pattern `w_1_1_1` in their name.

Comment: Thanks for your response, It is useful however I need to obtain that variables' coefficient from all constraints.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the [Column](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/8.1/refman/py_column.html) class of gurobipy.  It allows you to access the incidence information for a given `Var` object.  Here is a simple example you could use as a starting point:

```
import gurobipy as gp

m = gp.Model()
x = m.addVars(3)
m.addConstr(2 * x[0] + x[1] == 9, name="Cone")
m.addConstr(-x[0] + x[2] >= 1, name="Ctwo")
m.update()
col = m.getCol(x[0])
for i in range(col.size()):
    coef = col.getCoeff(i)
    row = col.getConstr(i)
    print("x[0] coef/row pair: {}/{}".format(coef, row.ConstrName))
```

So we create a model with three variables, and two constraints, and want to print all coefficients of the first variable `x[0]`, along with the constraint name that the variable is incident to.  Running the above snippet on my machine I see:

> x[0] coef/row pair: 2.0/Cone
>    x[0] coef/row pair: -1.0/Ctwo